# Creating Joomla Accounts outside of a web interface

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to create a Joomla account outside the web interface.  I want to create one from my Java application.  If so can you give me an idea about the best way to do this?

These are my thoughts so far:
1.  Create a php page that inserts the data directly into the database (but is there more to an account than simply the users table).
2.  Posting the data to the register page (but will it then detect that I am not using the web interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can:

- Use php to achieve it, [inheriting from JUser class like explained in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904809/how-can-i-create-a-new-joomla-user-account-from-within-a-script/1904855#1904855);
- Create a component using JUser in you Joomla installation, and use xml-rpc to register users using this component by calling a service from you Java application.