# Membership System For Website and IOS application

Tags: android, ios, xcode, joomla, membership

I am currently making an app and website. Is there a system around that will integrate with Joomla website AND an ios application (android would be a plus!). This system would need to have the ability for different premium plans.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing sounds unique so I doubt there is a system out there to fit your needs. What you can do is write your own component for Joomla such that you make an API with a number of different methods that when queried returns a JSON response. Have a look at my answer to this question ([Joomla Login Authentication from external app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176595/joomla-login-authentication-from-external-app/6533701#6533701)) in order to get a sense of how to do this.