# How to include the JAuthentication class of Joomla 2.5 in external scripts

Tags: authentication, joomla, include, external

I want to make a script which will login the user into Joomla and there isn't any official documentation on how to this at http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/User/JAuthentication.html

Comment: Think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176595/joomla-login-authentication-from-external-app

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with someone who requested me to login in a Joomla 2.5 website from an external custom HTML form. I'm a begginer in this matter, but I found a quite helpful script, since it works right the way I needed (all the credits for [this](http://www.jonijnm.es/web/foro/717-otros/19756-crear-una-sesion-de-joomla-desde-un-php-externo.html) web site).

I don't use the JAuthentication class, but the JFactory::getApplication object and its login method to authenticate to Joomla:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    define('_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));

    require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
    $app =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $app->initialise();

    //echo "<br>";print_r($app);

    $credentials = array();
    $credentials['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $credentials['password'] = $_POST['password'];

    //echo "<br>Login res: ".$app->login($credentials);

    if($app->login($credentials) == 1)
        header('location: http://www.johnabril.com/seguro_desmp');      
}
?>
```

As you can see, you just have to send an username and password strings from your HTML form, and it's done.

Hope it helps.