# Single sign on My joomla site and jobportal (jammit jobs) on same domain?

Tags: php, joomla1.5, single-sign-on

I have a joomla site and i have added another job portal at same domain.Supoose my site is www.abc.com which is joomla site and www.abc.com/jobs is jammit job portal . HOW i do single signon(SSO) my Joomla sites and jammit jobs(Job portal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a "magic" solution: you have to write something we call "bridge" in programming.

Create a **signon script** that uses the APIs of both Joomla and Jammit Jobs for achieving authentication from external applications.

You can start from here: 
[Joomla Login Authentication from external app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176595/joomla-login-authentication-from-external-app)

Or you can search on the web for pre-made Single Sign On (SSO) solutions, like this one: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/auto-login/19547

Comment: But i dont want to use cookies for that and my databse for both sites are different any idea.?

Comment: Databases will always be different, in fact you'll have to duplicate the user info. Why don't you want to use cookies? They are the only way we know to login people.

Comment: But i think there are security concern with cookies and if i create external enviornment for joomla than how a use already logged in in joomla shows login in jamit .Is open id a solution for my problem? Thank you gd1 for replying

Comment: OpenID may be a solution, as long as both CMS support it (seach for extensions). No, cookies are no security concern, if they expire soon.

Comment: then how should i start with OpenID, as i am new to it...thank you very much for replying and helping me gd1... one more thing which one is better CAS or OpenID is aspect of my problem..is it done by using OpenAuth also...

Comment: ok i admit that cookies are good solution for my problem, now gd1 can you show me the way to start....

Comment: hi gd1 i am stuck i am working with cookies but dont know the approach to do that problem. any idea or suggestion

Comment: OK give me some time to check it out