# Password encryption in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I am creating user with web service in joomla. this is my password encryption code

```
    $password= $_GET["password"];

$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password);
$password = $crypt . ':' . $salt;
```

but if i am trying to login in website with this password. Password not match with database. I am using joomla version 1.5
Please give any suggestion

Comment: You should also stop work on this project and immediately upgrade to J2.5 or J3.x. Joomla 1.5 is a hacker magnet and it is only a matter of time before your site is compromised. Save yourself the trouble and upgrade before it happens.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 2.5 user table passwords are saved as MD5 hashed strings. If you are to created a new user, You will have to generated a MD5 hashed password for the user as well as assign the user to a particular group which are saved in the user group table.

Read more

[How can I create a new Joomla user account from within a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904809/how-can-i-create-a-new-joomla-user-account-from-within-a-script)

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2114878

## Advise

`$password= $_GET["password"];` <--- This is not a good idea. NEVER

Comment: I am trying to create login service for app but user register from app and again login with this username and password from my joomla website user not able to login with this password reset password in website and then login in website successful