# Can Joomla and Moodle share the same database?

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, moodle

I know this is a hardcore programmer's site and I am more of a theorist/researcher, so bear with me with my question and my terminologies. I would like to pick your brains on this matter.

We have an existing website developed using Moodle. The website is technically a Learning Management System that grades users after each course. Now we want to make it more interactive by adding a game element to it. We will develop a tab that will redirect the users to Joomla website (which will look exactly like the moodle one) but they wont know they are on a different platform. This tab will display the users profile including his grade or at least the numerical value of his "Grades" which will be labeled as "Points". I know the numerical value of the user's Grades are stored somewhere in Moodle but is it possible for that value to be a reference of the User's points in the Joomla platform?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to synchronise the logins between Moodle and Joomla. A "single sign on". Have a look at [these integrations for Joomla](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Integrations#Joomla).

But I would personally develop the game as a local plugin in Moodle rather than using Joomla: [Local plugins - MoodleDocs](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins).

Answer (score 0):

You can share same DB for Moodle and Joomla.

But you have to keep in mind while your user details are stored in Moodles at that time you have to submit those info to the Joomla user table too.

Then you can achieve your goal. For setting up the Joomla user manually you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271930/create-a-user-when-i-submit-a-form/19272590#19272590)

Hope it make sense..

Answer (score 0):

you can share the moodle website with joomla that possibly submit those user table which is acquired from moodle

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but make sure that user detail must be synchronized between both system tables(which has user information).